How to remote to a PC through another PC in VSCode
I have two PCs, and I can ssh to PC1 but cannot ping PC2. However PC1 can ssh to PC2. How can I set up in VSCode so that I can debug the python cdes on PC2 directly? Thanks!

Use a ProxyJump ssh PC2 -J PC1. You can add it to your ~/.ssh/config, too
